# $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$ whenever $f(x,y)=0\implies f(x,y)=g(y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I'm reading a book on differential equations using symmetries, and at some point the author seems to imply that if $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$ whenever $f(x,y)=0$, but $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\ne 0$ when $f(x,y)=0$, then $f(x,y)$ is independent of $x$, but I can't seem to reason out why this is true (assume $f$ is analytic if it helps).

I posted a possible explanation in the comments. I think it should extend to functions of an arbitrary number of variables as well...

Comment: is this 'whenever' meant as an equivalence?, so do you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0\ \Leftrightarrow f(x,y)=0$?

Comment: No it's not an equivalence. I think I may have figured it out. If $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$ when $f(x,y)=0$ but $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\ne 0$ then there is a curve where $f(x,y)=0$, and on this curve $\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}=0$, and since $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$ this gives $y(x)=c$, so that the curve is flat in $x$ and if $f$ is analytic this gives that it is independent of $x$...

Comment: It seems correct to me. I guess you can make this rigorous by involving the implicit function theorem and first show $f$ is independent of $x$ in a neighborhood of some point with $f(x,y)=0$ and use analyticity to conclude it holds everywhere.

Comment: Eh actually I think it's wrong. The mixed derivatives need not vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the claim is true. Consider the function
$$f(x,y):=y(2+x)\qquad \bigl(|x|<1,\>|y|<1\bigr)\ .$$
This function vanishes in the points $(x,0)$ $\>(-1<x<1)$, and nowhere else in its domain. In these points we have
$f_x(x,0)=0$ and $f_y(x,0)=2+x\ne0$, whence $f$ has the properties assumed by your source. Nevertheless $f$ is not "a function of $y$ alone".

Comment: Hm nice example, but then I am confused as to what the author meant...is it possible it is true if the function is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f = f(x)$, here is a counterexample. You are claiming that $f'(x) = 0$ iff $f(x) = 0$ implies $f$ is constant.

Consider $f(x) = x^3$. Certainly both $f,f'$ are 0 only at $x=0$ but $f$ is clearly not constant.

Comment: You could just consider $f(x,y)=x^3$ to stay in the context of a function of two variables. Though this does not satisfy $\partial f/\partial y\neq 0$ where $f(x,y)=0$.